# How can I switch from python3.5 to python3.4 in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have taken over a project that was broken on accident. It's a web application running Debian Linux with Django. In the application's virtualenv it only runs python 3.5. All of these commands return python 3.5 as the version:

```
python -V
pythong3.4 -V
pip -V
pip3 -V
```

I've tried using `apt remove (and purge) python3.5`, `apt remove (and purge) python3`, and deleting every 3.5 folder from the command `whereis python3.5`.

How can I remove 3.5 and only use 3.4?

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221341/downgrade-virtualenv-to-2-7-from-3-5-3

Answer (score 0):

Typically when working in Python and you want to use different language versions or different packages within an environment, you would create a new virtualenv for each specific Python version.

So to sum it up:

```
python3.4 -m venv name_for_venv
```

As you can see when you activate and you're using the specific virtual env you created, the Python3 version for it will be Python3.4